# Is "join" in this context ambiguous?

Tags: word-choice

During this internship, I joined the on-line training program which was given by the company to the employees and aimed to help them grasp the new system.

I am the student of this program.  I am afraid that "join" is not clear here because I think that the reader will not be sure whether I joined this program as a teacher, an organizer, or a student. Which verb suits to my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If you worked as a student, you can avoid ambiguity with...
"During this internship, **I took/participated in/attended** the on-line training program which was given by the company to the employees and aimed to help them grasp the new system."

If you worked as a teacher, you can say "worked as an instructor", and add the missing comma.
"During this internship, I **worked as an instructor** for the on-line training program which was given by the company to the employees, to help them grasp the new system."

Answer (score 1):

"enrolled in" would suggest you are a student rather than a teacher. Teachers do not "enroll" in a class; the "roll" is a list of students only.